# Asynchronous messaging in websphare 855 setmessagelistener

Tags: asynchronous, jms, websphere-8

Hi am migrating my application from jrun to websphere server and it has functionality of asynchronous messaging usnig message listener.

```
public void startMessageListener(final String queueName,
        final MessageListener listener) throws Exception {
        QueueSession queueSession = createNewQueueSession();

        Queue queue = (Queue) queueContext.lookup(queueName);
        QueueReceiver queueReceiver = queueSession.createReceiver((queue));
        queueReceiver.setMessageListener(listener);
        //LOG Forging fix-Fortify Scan TTP 345546 -START

         log.debug("started queue " + queueName);
        //LOG Forging fix-Fortify Scan TTP 345546 -END

}
```

when i use same code in websphere it throws error javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Method setMessageListener not permitted
Because the JMS spec does not allow you to use this feature in a JEE Container.

Please help me to make it work with less code changes.

Comment: Just create MDB that will implement that functionality.

Comment: Thanks Gas... MDB works but i need to provide queue names dynamically to listener class and these names will come from database. This queue names different for every client and in MDB i didnt find work around for this. Please help me to get it resolved.

Comment: Rajesh, I dont know the specifics of your app, but I'd suggest to rearchitect it to use single input queue. Listening on undefined number of queues that may grow potentially indefinitely is not very scalable solution and will lead to exhaust of resources.